# Native iOS frameworks bringing Wordpress site to iPhone / Ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, wordpress, ios-frameworks

Are there iOS frameworks for speeding up the development of native iPhone / iPad apps for a Wordpress powered website? So, there is already a Wordpress site, and we want to create a native iOS app that will get it's data from the Wordpress site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with http://www.shoutem.com/ they can create nice app for you in a very little time..

There is a nice wp plugin.

(disclamer: I work for a sister company, FiveMinutes ltd.)

Answer (score 0):

You can always try PhoneGap.

is an HTML5 app platform that allows you to author native applications with web technologies and get access to APIs and app stores. PhoneGap leverages web technologies developers already know best... HTML and JavaScript

[Phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/)

Comment: PhoneGap is very generic and doesn't seem to provide specific Wordpress tools.

Comment: Yes, at first it seems very generic, although you can combine lots of tools to create some really sophisticated apps, look at some of the examples that people have made when using Sencha touch and phonegap